# mysql order by sum(column) grouped by another column with self-join

Tags: mysql

i have  table events:

```
create table events (
    time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    passes INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    fails INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    device_channel VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    device_name VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
    events_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);
```

containing the following data:

```
INSERT INTO events VALUES 
('2018-08-08 10:30:00',3000,15,'ch1','dev1',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:30:00',3000,12,'ch1','dev2',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:30:00',3000,9,'ch1','dev3',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:30:00',3000,11,'ch2','dev4',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:30:00',3000,10,'ch2','dev5',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:30:00',3000,8,'ch2','dev6',NULL),

('2018-08-08 10:45:00',4000,18,'ch1','dev1',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:45:00',4000,16,'ch1','dev2',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:45:00',4000,10,'ch1','dev3',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:45:00',4000,11,'ch2','dev4',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:45:00',4000,20,'ch2','dev5',NULL),
('2018-08-08 10:45:00',4000,10,'ch2','dev6',NULL);
```

i need to show the difference in passes and fails columns over the time interval and have created the following query:

```
SELECT a.time AS Start_time, b.time AS End_time ,a.device_channel AS Channel,a.device_name AS Device,b.passes-a.passes AS Passes, b.fails-a.fails AS Fails
  FROM events a
  JOIN events b 
    ON b.time > a.time AND b.device_name = a.device_name;
```

This query generates the following results:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+-------+
| Start_time          | End_time            | Channel | Device | Passes | Fails |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+-------+
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev1   |   1000 |     3 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev2   |   1000 |     4 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev3   |   1000 |     1 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev4   |   1000 |     0 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev5   |   1000 |    10 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev6   |   1000 |     2 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I need however to order the table on SUM(Fails) grouped on device_channel so the table ends up as follows after query:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+-------+
| Start_time          | End_time            | Channel | Device | Passes | Fails |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+-------+
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev4   |   1000 |     0 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev5   |   1000 |    10 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev6   |   1000 |     2 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev1   |   1000 |     3 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev2   |   1000 |     4 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev3   |   1000 |     1 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+--------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I have tried appending the following ORDER BY clause to query but it does not appear to work:

```
  ORDER BY SUM(b.fails-a.fails) OVER (PARTITION BY channel.channel_num) DESC;
```

Any help much appreciated.

based on input from @vinay Chhabra i created a query which provides the required result:

```
SELECT t1.*
  FROM 
    (
    SELECT a.time AS Start_time, b.time AS End_time ,a.device_channel AS Channel,a.device_name AS Device, b.fails-a.fails AS Fails
    FROM events a
    JOIN events b 
        ON b.time > a.time AND b.device_name = a.device_name
    ) AS t1

 JOIN
    (
    SELECT a.device_channel AS Channel,a.device_name AS Device, b.fails-a.fails AS Fails, SUM(b.fails-a.fails) AS Sumfails
    FROM events a
    JOIN events b 
        ON b.time > a.time AND b.device_name = a.device_name
    Group by Channel
    ) t2
ON t1.Channel = t2.Channel 
ORDER by Sumfails DESC, Fails DESC;

+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+-------+
| Start_time          | End_time            | Channel | Device | Fails |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+-------+
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev5   |    10 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev6   |     2 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch2     | dev4   |     0 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev2   |     4 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev1   |     3 |
| 2018-08-08 10:30:00 | 2018-08-08 10:45:00 | ch1     | dev3   |     1 |
+---------------------+---------------------+---------+--------+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I suspect there is a more elegant solution however.

Comment: Use a proper `GROUP BY`.  Your query won't even run because it doesn't make sense.  When you group by `Channel`, which value of `Device` is retrieved??

Comment: @Eric the above query run for me on MySQL v5.6.23 and v8.0.12 and produces the required output above. ch1 contains dev1,dev2 and dev3 whereas ch2 contains dev4,dev5 and dev6.

Comment: Learn a good habit of using proper `GROUP BY`.  Probably `MySQL` is the only dbms that allow messed up `GROUP BY`.  Your query won't even run in other dbms.

Comment: @Eric can you provide a proper query that provides the required output please ..be interested to learn what the correct approach is here.

Answer (score 0):

Is this You are asking for.
Try out:-

```
SELECT a.time AS Start_time, b.time AS End_time ,a.device_channel AS Channel,a.device_name AS Device,b.passes-a.passes AS Passes, b.fails-a.fails AS Fails
  FROM events a
  JOIN events b 
    ON b.time > a.time AND b.device_name = a.device_name
    ORDER BY fails  desc;
```

and for channel wise:-

```
SELECT a.time AS Start_time, b.time AS End_time ,a.device_channel AS Channel,a.device_name AS Device,b.passes-a.passes AS Passes, b.fails-a.fails AS Fails
  FROM events a
  JOIN events b 
    ON b.time > a.time AND b.device_name = a.device_name
    ORDER BY channel ,fails desc;
```

Comment: no I want to order on SUM(fails) grouped by device_channel. So as shown above SUM(fails) = 12 over ch2 and SUM(fails) = 8 over ch1. Therefore if we order based on SUM(fails) grouped on device_channel  DESC we should get 3 x rows with ch2 followed by 3 x rows ch1as shown above.

Comment: this query returns as you have mentioned in your question.I am not able to understand what "SUM(fails) = 12 over ch2 and SUM(fails) = 8 over ch1" means can you provide the output you want

Comment: in the question above the second table is the output that I want ..this shows fails ordered by 0,10,2,3,4,1 where 0,10,2 are associated with ch2 and 3,4,1 with ch1

Comment: That is the output you are getting with this query

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this below query.

```
SELECT derv_res.device_channel, SUM(derv_res.diff) AS total_fails 
FROM 
(SELECT     a.device_channel, a.device_name , (b.fails - a.fails) AS diff
FROM EVENTS a
INNER JOIN EVENTS b 
ON b.time > a.time AND 
b.device_name = a.device_name 
GROUP BY 
a.device_channel,
a.device_name) AS derv_res
GROUP BY derv_res.device_channel
ORDER BY total_fails DESC ;
```

Comment: this just displays 2 rows ..I need to see all 6 rows as shown above. many thanks for your input

Comment: Yes , there are two unique device channels . so it will give two records . If we want to get 6 rows then inner query is enough . but need to add order by diff desc for inner query .